# Can't configure Eclipse for running a perl script using the EPIC plugin?

Tags: eclipse, perl, configuration, epic

I just installed EPIC (Perl in Eclipse Plugin) in Eclipse Indigo.  I'm running win7.  I read that I needed to install padwalker, which I did also.  I then created a Perl project and a script file.

Everything looks good, but when I try to setup the run or debug configuration, the project isn't referenced in the Project Selection dialog under run configurations in Eclipse, as one I can select and in the EPIC user guide it shows all projects should be available?

I'm pointing to the "C:\Perl\bin\perl5.8.8.exe" in my PerlEpic preferences.  Is there something else I need to do that I've missed?

After doing some research, I see that the reason the project won't run is that general projects can't run under eclipse, only java projects, those with a [java nature](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html) associated with them. (ie have a project and a classpath folder with the "J" icon designated in their source file under the Project View).  My Perl project has a "Perl Nature" associated with it, so it's not a java project perse.

**So the real question is how do I create a Perl project in eclipse, but still be able to run it like I do a java project?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after much searching, I missed this in the EPIC user guide on [creating launch configurations](http://epic-ide.org/guide/ch06s02.php).  It pays to read through the [user guide](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http://www.epic-ide.org/downloads/EPIC_User%2527s_Guide.pdf&ei=6vBHT4ebMcvXiALGiZHbDQ&usg=AFQjCNFBQ-YAPigy-bqWM8OX1VWqUFgNqA) for this stuff.  You have to create a new launch configuration since it's not java and it doesn't have a main method in the file.

One other item, to use the debugger in eclipse you need to run ppm from a dos command prompt.  This will launch a GUI dialog window for the Perl module utility for ActivePerl that runs on Windows. Then select the PadWalker perl module to install it.

After that everything worked great!